# How to write data in Avro format to Kafka from Flink?

Tags: scala, apache-kafka, apache-flink, avro

For reading `Avro` data from `Kafka` we have `AvroDeserializationSchema`. But what about writing?

Answer (score 0):

There is the `AvroRowSerializationSchema` which can be used to serialize `Rows`. If you need to serialize a specific type, then I would suggest to implement your own schema since Flink does not offer any other Avro `SerializationSchemas` at the moment.

Comment: Yes, I saw this runtime error: "Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: MyType cannot be cast to org.apache.flink.types.Row", even though `new AvroRowSerializationSchema(MyType.class)` compiles fine. Is there a way to make `MyType` work with `AvroRowSerializationSchema`? I'll consider my own `SerializationSchemas` as the last resort. I'm still learning Flink and the data types are not final and change often. I don't want to update my `SerializationSchemas` every time I change my data types. I'd rather to use a generic solution that handles any data types automatically.

Comment: So you may try JSON string to achieve flexible structure modification for developing purpose.